# Sublime Text - show open files on the left

Tags: sublimetext

Is there a way to show the files that are open in SublimeText on the left of the screen, in a simple list?

I'd simply like the open files to appear on the left in a clickable way like this

```
file1.txt
file2.css
file3.htm
etc
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Go to the "View" menu and choose "Side Bar", then "Show Open Files"

[image]

Comment: Situations like this makes me wish that the answer with the most upvotes was automatically and dynamically displayed as the correct answer.

Comment: Also, is there a way to set this as the default behavior? Can't find anything in the default config file.

Comment: @AndreasBergström yeah, I wondered that too - something that can be added to Preferences.sublime-settings for the user

Comment: @iamkeir have you found out what would it be?

Comment: surely there is a command that is not referred to in the default key bindings, like 'toggle_tabs' for Hide Tabs

Answer (score 21):

Right click on open file in editor...
Click on Reveal in Side Bar option, it will sync the open file with side bar

Answer (score 13):

`Ctrl+K+B` will reveal the 'Side bar', with open file information. It is really worth using projects, they are really simple and provides for easy folder/project/file switching.
I also strongly reccomend going to `preferences>Key Bindings - Default` through the menus, and looking at all the functionality and keyboard shortcuts. Also 'preferences>Settings - Defualt`, shows you all of the configurable options (there are a lot). These are basically 'must dos' for getting full goodness out of Sublime.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it only using keyboard, `Command + Shift + P` and select `View: Toggle Open Files in Side Bar`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's the key binding to run this shortcut using the keyboard:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+shift+j"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar" },
]
```