# How to highlight files in the side bar that have been modified since the last commit with Git in Sublime Text 3 (like Atom does )?

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Atom highlights files that have been modified since the last commit in the side bar:

[image: highlight modified file in Atom]

Is there any way to do this in Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This is currently not possible according to [this issue on the sublime-text-git plugin repository](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/204).

### Original Answer*

**Before I realized that OP was talking about Git modified status, as opposed to unsaved changes.*

This isn't exactly the same, but you can get close with built-in features.

You can follow the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835602/sublime-text-show-open-files-on-the-left) to show open files in the side bar (**View** > **Side Bar** > **Show Open Files**). This adds a section called *OPEN FILES* at the top of the side bar. With the default theme, any modified file will have a little gray circle next to it. It may look different if you are using a custom theme.

In this example, I have three files open. The gray circle by `modified file` tells you it has been modified. (`TODO.md` is highlighted because it's currently selected.)

[image: Sublime Text 3 - Open and Modified Files]

Comment: This setting just show the modified stutus(no-save/save) of `files opened in the tab`.  And What I wanna solve is to show the modified stutus comparing to the original files last commited. And maybe this feature can't be implemented due to the LACK of Sublime's sidebar [API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)!

Comment: @RobinChen I didn't realize that, when you said "modified", you mean with regards to source control. Did you have a specific version control system in mind, e.g. Git? If so, you should update to your question to clarify that.

Comment: I'm now using Git to control versions. And sorry about that I didn't give my question exactly at first, thank you for updating the question title 